# how do I change instanced class variables

Tags: java, instance-variables

my code simplified looks something like:

```
//class 1
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Process process = new Process(0); //creates new process with ID of 0 
      process.id = 1; //error - I can't call and change process.id here
      System.out.println(process.id);

   } 
}

//class 2:
public class Process()
{
   //constructor
   public Process(int tempID)
   {
    int id = tempID;
   }
}
```

Where I have the comment error is what I'm stuck with. I want to access and change the id variable of this instanced class I have, but I'm not sure how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Defined id as an instance variable.

Since id is defined inside the method locally that is why you can access it using `p.id`.
So create id as an instance variable like and for updating its value create a setter method. So your class would look like this.

```
public class Process(){

  public int id;   //<- Instance Varaible

 //constructor
 public Process(int tempID){
    int id = tempID;
 }
 
 //Setter method
 public void setId(int id){
     int id = tempID;**strong text**
 }

}
```

Now you can change the value like this

```
 Process p = new Process(0);
 p.setId(1);          // Change Value
 System.out.println(p.id);
```